# Detect that UseStartup<TStartup> was called in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

When configuring ASP.NET Core startup there's this:

```cs
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder => {
  //add services here or in Startup.ConfigureServices()   // (1)
  webHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
})
.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => {
  //add services here                                     // (2a)
})
.UseMyServices()                                          // (2b)
```

I must register something **after** the web host starts. I could do so at location `(2a)`, or in a helper `UseMyServices()` extension method `(2b)`, which is effectively the same thing.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder UseMyServices(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
  hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, serviceCollection) => {
    //add services here
  };
}
```

Inside `UseServices()` I want to do a sanity check to ensure the code was placed at the correct location. Can I use `hostBuilderContext` or `serviceCollection` to detect that the `UseStartup<T>()` call was already made?

I looked in the `serviceCollection` to find something interesting, e.g. `IStartup`, but didn't find anything useful. Maybe I'm not looking for the right thing.

**Summary:** how do I detect that the `UseStartup<TStartup>` call has been made?

Comment: FYI the `.ConfigureContainer` callbacks, will run after `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Does the order actually make a difference here? I wouldn't think that the order of `.ConfigureWebHostDefaults` and `.ConfigureServices` would affect the execution order of methods within, unless you've got `ConfigureServices` inside startup, I guess.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Do you mean I could leverage that somehow? I can't think of a way. Thanks I'll give it more thought.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes the order ensures that, for example, a hosted service that relies on other services will work. If placed before, then it could fail. Example from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli#startasync-1).

Comment: The order each `.ConfigureServices` is executed should be preserved, which will define the order of any `IEnumerable<T>` service collections. And for services like `IHostedService`, that order might be very important.

Comment: As a concrete example, a hosted service that depends on an EF context, if placed before the webhost starts, will probably fail - as the context is not yet set up.

Comment: In _that_ specific scenario, you will have to manage your own scope with EF context as that is Scoped service IIRC

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by `must register something after the web host starts`. When the webhost starts, the container is already built and you can't add anything to it.

Comment: @JohanP See the example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli#startasync-1). If the app is not yet running, some services *could* fail. It depends on the nature of the service. I've had this problem before, the order matters in some weird cases.

Comment: @lonix I don't see any examples in that link of services that could fail. If you have a `Scoped` service, you will have to manage your own scope inside the HostedService as HostedService is a `Singleton`

Comment: @JohanP Sorry maybe I'm mixing up the examples here, but I've definitely had problems in the past when I registered something in the wrong order. That's the point of this question, which is to find a way to detect that the call was made at the right time.

Comment: @lonix if you're working with middleware then order is important otherwise _possibly_ when you have multiple implementations of the same interface other than that, I cannot see how the order of `service.AddSingleton` calls e.g. could mess up the object graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All services will be registered before `Configure` is called in `Startup`, regardless of whether the hook for registration is before or after `UseWebHostDefault`. If this is your concern, there's nothing that can be done. Note that the order that calls to `ConfigureServices` are made will be respected.

I've not really found any "good" solutions, but I did notice that the code for `ConfigureWebHost` (and therefore `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`) registers `GenericWebHostService` as an `IHostedService`, so maybe you could use this.

The issue here is that the service is `internal` and it's an implementation detail, so there's no guarantee that this won't be changed/removed/renamed in a future version. Anyway, if you are OK with that risk, then you could write the following code in your extension method:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder UseMyServices(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
    return hostBuilder
        .ConfigureServices(svc =>
        {
            if (svc.Any(svc => svc.ServiceType == typeof(IHostedService) && svc.ImplementationType.Name == "GenericWebHostService"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After UseWebHostDefault");
            }
            // do your other service registrations
        });
}
```

The problem here is that this doesn't specifically detect that `UseStartup` was called, just that `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` was run.

--

Another thing I've found is that UseStartup adds a property to the `HostBuilderContext` properties ([code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/GenericHost/GenericWebHostBuilder.cs#L282)). Unfortunately the key it uses is a `private` instance field in an `internal` class (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/GenericHost/GenericWebHostBuilder.cs#L28)). Even if you wanted to take the risk of implementation changes causing runtime errors here, I'm not sure how you would access the key from this class.

If you just want to check if `Startup` in your project has been called, you could write something like this to check if its instance has been registered:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder UseMyServices(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
    return hostBuilder
        .ConfigureServices((ctx, svc) =>
        {
            if (ctx.Properties.Any(p => p.Value?.GetType() == typeof(Startup)))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After Startup");
            }
            // do your other service registrations
        });
}
```

Comment: `ctx.Properties` is the trick to make this work, but like you said it's an implementation detail that cannot be trusted. Nonetheless thanks for this in depth investigation!